# How to count individual elements in a pair - scheme ?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(cons 2 (cons ( cons 2 3 ) (cons 4 5 )))
```

This gives me a list that looks like this : `(2 (2 . 3) 4 . 5)` when I try to count the number of elements in this list the output is `3` as exepected.

How do I calculate the number of individual elements of a pair ? The output in this case should be `5` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, the question is essentially asking for the number of atoms in a list structure (not necessarily null-terminated proper lists):

```
(define (count-all seq)
  (cond ((null? seq) 0)
        ((not (pair? seq)) 1)
        (else (+ (count-all (car seq))
                 (count-all (cdr seq))))))
```

It works on sequences of elements like this:

- If the sequence is empty, it has zero elements
- If the sequence is not a cons cell (a pair of elements), it's because it's a single element - an atom
- Otherwise add the elements of both the `car` and the `cdr` of the sequence

It works as expected for arbitrarily nested list structures:

```
(count-all '(2 (2 . 3) 4 . 5))
=> 5

(count-all '(1 (2 . (3 (4 . 5) 6)) 7 . 8))
=> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem recursively for arbitrarily deeply nested lists.

```
(define (atom? x) (not (pair? x)))

(define (count-atoms lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) 0) ; nothing to count, return 0
          ((atom? lst) 1) ; lst contains only one thing, return 1
          (else           ; otherwise, lst contains multiple elements
             (+ (count-atoms (car lst))       ; add the number of atoms in the first position
                (count-atoms (cdr lst))))))   ; to the number of atoms in the rest of the list
```

**EDIT:**  This is a duplicate to Oscar's answer.  I did not see that he had answered when I hit submit, but will leave this here since I feel the comments are useful.